# How get value in checkbox datatables jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

How get value if checkbox checked is 1 and no is 0,

This my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#table').DataTable({
        "paging": true,
        "lengthChange": true,
        "searching": true,
        "ordering": true,
        "info": false,
        "responsive": true,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "pageLength": 10,
        "ajax": {
          "url": "../adapter/jobaccess/data.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: ({kd_entitas: kd_entitas,
            usergroup: cmbUsergroup})
        },
        "columns": [
        { title: 'No.', name: 'No.', data: "urutan" },
        { title: 'Menu', data: "menudesc"},
        { title: 'Code', data: "menukey" },
        { title: 'Show', data: "alloshow1" },
        { title: 'Create', data: "allonew1" },
        { title: 'Edit', data: "alloedit1" },
        { title: 'Delete', data: "allodel1" },
        { title: 'Approve', data: "alloappr1" },
        ]
  })
});
```

[image: This my result from load database]

is it possible to get value from my jquery code ?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Please post your code or provide a link to a jsfiddle/codepen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for some thing like `$(selector).prop('checked')` which will return true if is checked and false if not checked. And you can bind click event to that check box. Here is working example.

```js
let count = 0;
$('#table').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
  count ++;
  if($(this).prop('checked')){
    console.log(1);
  } else {
    console.log(0);
  }
  console.log("Count: " + count);
});
```

```css
.center {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
td, th {
    padding: 5px;   
}
tr {
    height: 25px;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" style="empty-cells:hide;" border="1"   cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Field 1</th><th>Field 2</th><th>Field 3</th><th>Field 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="center">
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="center">
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="center">
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="center">
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you... I looking for that, but how  add with name of field... mean like "field 4 + console.log(1))?

Comment: and how count if checked per field?

Comment: count click on single input ?

Comment: when i click checkbox so auto count per field?

Comment: do you need the count of individual checkbox or count for all checkbox.

Comment: for all checkbox

Comment: @SamsulHuda simply declare one global variable and increase it by 1 on every click.